# Difference in EAR Deployed in Websphere Application server. (war to ear )

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, war, ear

I have a web application(Myapp) configured in eclipse. 
So in order to Deploy it in Websphere v5.1 I have to export it to EAR.

> **Scenario 1:**  In eclipse--> new --> Enterprise Application Project
>   -->Named as MyappEAR--> Selected Existing Module(Myapp)--> Finish. Now I got MyappEAR in Project Explorer. Right click on MyappEAR export to
>   EAR. Done. Got MyappEAR.ear file with Myapp.war inside it.(Includes
>   META-INF and xml)
>
> Deployed MyappEAR.ear in Websphere, Deployed Successfully. But when i
>   tried to start MyappEAR it ends up with this error  **SRVE0054E: An error
>   occurred while loading Web application** (No more information found).

---

> **Scenario 2**: Eclipse--> right click on Myapp export to war--> Got
>   Myapp.war--> Deleted existing myapp from Project explorer.
>   File-->Import-->WAR--> enabled Add project to an EAR and named it as
>   MyappEAR-->finish Right click on MyappEAR-->export to EAR. Done . Got
>   MyappEAR.ear with same stuff as above.
>
> Deloplyed and Started working fine.

Now my question is What's the difference in both ways causing that error? (even checked with beyond compare, everything is same).

Websphere app server v5.1, 
Java 1.4,
Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: Do you have the diagnostic trace enabled?  If not, do that.  The additional log messages may shed some light on the cause of your distress.

Comment: And as a side note, WAS 5.1 reached end-of-life nearly 5 years ago.  6.0 support ended 3 years ago, and 6.1 support ends this year.  It's probably time to think about upgrading.  If this turns out to be a WAS bug, you're pretty much out of luck at this point.

Comment: Yes, Diagnostic trace is enabled. But atleast its working fine now. and YES WAS 5.1 is very old, But company still using that and they don't want to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

We have a Maven project and it builds the EAR after we run mvn clean install.Then I take EAR from target folder and deploy it in server.

In local setup,Just add the project in server and start the server.Normally it works.